# How to set singular name for a table in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
type user struct {
    ID       int
    Username string `gorm:"size:255"`
    Name     string `gorm:"size:255"`
}
```

I want to create a table 'user' using this model. But the table name is automatically set to 'users'. I know it is gorm's default behavior. But I want the table name to be 'user'.

Comment: for sake of completeness: You can use `db.SingularTable(true)` to use singular tablenames globally.

Answer (score 52):

Set method `TableName` for your struct.

```
func (user) TableName() string {
    return "user"
}
```

Link: https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#conventions

Comment: Just realized that OP was using `user` instead of `User`.

Comment: Would I also need to call this method or just declaring this way would do the work?

Comment: https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name
Now the document about customized table name is placed here.

Answer (score 24):

Gorm has a in-built method for that that will be set in global level so all tables will be singular.

For gorm v1, you could do:

```
db.SingularTable(true)
```

For v2, it's a little more verbose:

```
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(connStr), &gorm.Config{
    NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
        SingularTable: true,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly set a table name, you would have to create an interface `Tabler` with `TableName` method, and then create a receiver method (defined in the interface) for the struct:

```
type user struct {
    ID       int
    Username string `gorm:"size:255"`
    Name     string `gorm:"size:255"`
}

type Tabler interface {
  TableName() string
}

// TableName overrides the table name used by User to `profiles`
func (user) TableName() string {
  return "user"
}
```