# Can the gorm column tag specify more than one field name? Or can case be ignored?

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

Now I'm using two tables with the same field name but different casing. But I just want to define a struct to deserialize these two mysql table fields? Can it be done?

e.g.

table1:

```
 create table users1(
            username varchar (65) not null,
            password varchar (65) not null
        )
```

table2:

```
 create table users2(
            userName varchar (65) not null,
            passWord varchar (65) not null
        )
```

However, only one struct can be defined, e.g.：

```
type User struct {
            userName   string    `gorm:"column:username"`   
            PassWord   string    `gorm:"column:passeord"`
        }
```

How should I define a struct? Or can it be done in some other way???

Answer (score 0):

When you define a struct it means that this structure will belongs only to one table, so in your case decision is create another struct for second table

```
type UserOne struct {
   username string `gorm:"column:username"
   password string `gorm:"column:password"
}

type UserTwo struct {
   username string `gorm:"column:userName"
   password string `gorm:"column:passWord"
}
```

if you will migrate these both structures gorm will create 2 tables `user_one` and `user_two`, if you want to operate with already existing tables you can change it names with gorm func, here the example [How to set singular name for a table in gorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44589060/how-to-set-singular-name-for-a-table-in-gorm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But my current requirement is: can I use only one struct to receive data from two tables with the same field name but different casing? Can the gorm framework itself do it? It seems that this cannot be done at present!

Comment: short answer  is no